# Is possible to reflect an struct from ast

Tags: go, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree

I trying to implement some way to get the reflect.TypeOf() from a *ast.TypeSpec, to work with the struct without needs to import it in the code (I will explain later). For now I have this project structure:

```
.
├─ main.go
└─ entities
   ├─ costumer.go
   └─ person.go
```

Files:

```golang
// entities/costumer.go
package entities

import "time"

type Costumer struct {
    PersonId  int
    S         *int
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt *time.Time
    Goods     []struct {
        Name    string
        GoodsId int
    }
    Goods2
}

func (*Costumer) TableName() string {
    return "CustomName"
}

type Goods2 struct {
    Name     string
    Goods2Id int
}
```

```golang
// entities/person.go
package entities

type Person struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

```golang
// main.go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/printer"
    "go/token"
    "log"
)

// Main aa
func main() {
    // Create the AST by parsing src.
    fset := token.NewFileSet() // positions are relative to fset
    packages, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, "./entities", nil, 0)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, pack := range packages {

        for _, file := range pack.Files {
            // Inspect the AST and print all identifiers and literals.
            ast.Inspect(file, func(n ast.Node) bool {
                switch x := n.(type) {
                case *ast.TypeSpec: // Gets Type assertions
                    fmt.Println(x.Name.Name)

                    v := x.Type.(*ast.StructType)
                    for _, field := range v.Fields.List {

                        for _, name := range field.Names {

                            // get field.Type as string
                            var typeNameBuf bytes.Buffer
                            err := printer.Fprint(&typeNameBuf, fset, field.Type)
                            if err != nil {
                                log.Fatalf("failed printing %s", err)
                            }
                            fmt.Printf("field %+v has type %+v\n", name.Name, typeNameBuf.String())
                        }

                    }
                    fmt.Println()

                }

                return true
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And I need some way to get `Costumer`, `Goods2` and `Person` structs to use in the code. For now I want specifically call the `Costumer.TableName` method and receive the result of it.

I can't import the package because later it will be a CLI and will recive just the folder to parse/inspect (`parser.ParseDir(fset, "<folder goes here>", nil, 0)`)

So any ideas, suggestions or tips?

Comment: It is not possible to load an execute code using the go/ast package. Is your higher-level goal to associate a custom table name with a struct?  If so, there are good solutions to that problem.

Comment: My main goal is create a full featured ef like cli in golang, I found a interresting package thats could help me in this case called github.com/modern-go/reflect2, here is some examples https://github.com/elastic/apm-server/blob/master/elasticsearch/config_test.go#L110-L133

Comment: @MuffinTop maybe I will use ast to get all structs names exported and use reflect2.TypeByPackageName to get a struct itself, if it works I will aswer it with that

Comment: When I say EF I mean https://github.com/dotnet/efcore, I want to create a way to do migrations easier as "dotnet ef add migration Initial_Migration". For that I want to read structs from folder/package without import it to my CLI just receving metadata of it. And then create tables, columns and etc

Comment: I need to call a method, tableName was just an example

Comment: Compile the source files into an executable and call the function from that executable.

Answer (score 2):

A long time passed and I find a way:

After you parsed a AST file and get the structs from package, you could use reflection to create a struct in runtime with the following:

```golang
t := reflect.StructOf([]reflect.StructField{
    {
        Name: "A",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(int(0)),
        Tag:  `json:"a"`,
    },
    {
        Name: "B",
        Type: reflect.TypeOf(""),
        Tag:  `json:"B"`,
    },
    // Other fields ...
})

d := reflect.New(t).Interface() // Here you recived a struct as interface. And that's it.
```

Answer (score -6):

> Is possible to reflect an struct from ast in Go[...]?

No, you must redesign.

Comment: So any suggestion of redesign?

Comment: @Gunblades Unfortunately not  as I do not understand what you are trying to do.